# Get all languages that an item has a version in using Glass Mapper

Tags: glass-mapper, multilingual

Using the Sitecore API, I can use the following to get all of the languages that an item has a version in:

```
var itemLanguages = 
    ItemManager.GetContentLanguages(Sitecore.Context.Item)
        .Select(
            lang => 
                new 
                { 
                    Language = lang, 
                    HasLanguage = ItemManager.GetVersions(Sitecore.Context.Item, lang).Count > 0
                })
        .Where(langInfo => langInfo.HasLanguage)
        .Select(langInfo => langInfo.Language);
```

Since the `ItemManager` does not have any overloads for the `ItemManager.GetContentLanguages` or the `ItemManager.GetVersions` methods that accept item IDs instead of items, does anyone know of a way to map a glass property on a glass model that holds all of the languages that an item has a version in without doing an extra item-get, i.e. without re-getting the item as a `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item` via a `GetItem` call?